# Trying to figure out a multiplier effect based on how unpopular a selection is

Tags: statistics, game-theory

I am working on a game and am stuck trying to figure out the scoring mechanism.

Think of the game as a Fantasy Sports game, in which you select players who will compete in a real-life sporting event. At the end of the event, based on how well your players performed, you get points for each one.

The twist here is, each player receives a *multiplier effect* which helps to boost their score. This effect is to be based on how many people in the game chose that player (or how few).

For example:

[image: Score chart]

In the image above, we see that:

- A total of 10,000 users have signed up to play the game
- We have an example entry of someone selecting 5 players
- Against each of the player, we can see the number of other users that selected that player
- And a percentage showing how popular the player was

What I can't figure out is a formula that can be applied to the points earned that gives the final score for each player, taking into account their popularity. The *more* popular that player is, the less the multiplier should be. The less popular that player is, the higher that multiplier should be.

The motivation here is to reward people for picking *diamonds in the rough* instead of the most popular player and the obvious choice. This way, users are incentivized to take some chances and pick out-of-the-box players to get lucky with multipliers.

Sorry if this was too long winded. Appreciate any help or insight that anyone can provide.